# asp.net VNext Identity not working in RC1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g, asp.net-identity

Yesterday, I migrated my project from `beta7 to RC1.`
Everything works fine but I have the following issue.

In `beta7`, i used `EF 6.1.3` with `oracle code first` and in my startup class under Configure method I have `app.UseIdentity()` and its worked well. But in `RC1` it gives error to include `services.AddIdentity()` with application user and role. 
I have a separate function which add claims to the principal identity in my login part. Please guide me

Comment: Everything I've seen about Entity Framework 7 RC1 indicates that it doesn't have an Oracle provider at this stage so I doubt if it's going to work for you until one is released.

Comment: Actually I am not using EF 7.. but i can successfully connect to database without any problem.. my only problem here is I couldnt make identity to work with...

Comment: I think what you need is documented here http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingauthmembership.html where the call to AddIdentity is shown

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the update... actually i read this already.. Based on this, I think i have to create a new ApplicationUser and ApplicationDBContext.. But in Beta 7, its very simple, just adding app.UseIdentity() gives all comfort. In RC1, i dont understand how to use this ApplicationUser and ApplicationDBContext..